# What will be the fee for public insurance when unemployed?

Tags: germany, health-insurance

I've got German permanent residence (Niederlassungserlaubnis) and planning to take break from work for 2 - 3 months to travel and think on startup plans.

In this case, how much do I need to pay for medical insurance? Currently I've got AOK public health insurance.

Comment: I think you are much more likely to get a reliable answer from AOK than from a random person on the internet.

Comment: It depends on your income during this time (all sources, including, e.g., rent from flats that you own). To a minor degree, the individual rate of your local AOK (_Zusatzbeitrag_) also factors in.

Comment: @chirlu I stay in rented apartment and won't be having any income from salary or other sources, so any idea what is min I need to pay ?

Comment: If you’ve been working for long enough, you should be able to have it paid by the Agentur für Arbeit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not have any income during this time, you will be treated as if you had an income of € 1015 monthly (as of 2018). On this amount, you pay around 15% for health insurance and typically 2,8% for long-term care insurance. The exact rates depend on where you live, among other things.

Consequently, you will need to pay around € 180 a month.